# How to create function x times

Tags: javascript

I'm learning to code and i've come across a probably quite easy problem to solve.

I make a request from the database, that returns a number of users. For each user i create a few input fields like name, email etc.

Now what i want to do is use the same php variable (that contains the number of users), to create or repeat a function x times.

This is what i've tried so far.

```
var j = 0;

while (j <= i) { //i is the variable passed from php, containing the number of useres

    j++;

    $('#btnEdit'+j).click(function() {

        $("#prename"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#surname"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#function"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#prefix"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#phone_number"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#email"+j).removeAttr('disabled');


    });


}
```

The HTML looks something like this:

Input

```
<label>Prename</label>
<input name="prename" id="prename<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['db_prename_value']; ?>" maxlength="100" type="text" placeholder="Prename" disabled="disabled" />
```

Button

```
<input type="button" id="btnEdit<?php echo $i; ?>"
name="button<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Edit"></input>
```

To give a short explanation:

If the database returns 2 users, all the above fields are created for 2 users in php. User 1 will have prename1, surname1 etc. while user 2 will have prename2, surname2 and so on.

I won't know how many users get returned by the database so i can't just manually create the above snippet a set amount of times.

To clarify, i've already passed the variable from php to javascript (variable i). The question is how to repeat the javascript function x times, as the snippet i've posted is not working.

As far as my understanding goes, what my code does is iterate through the while loop x amount of times, but stops at this line, since the button is not being clicked.

```
    $('#btnEdit'+j).click(function() {
```

Maybe i'm just confused about how to do what i'm trying to do.

Let's make an example. If the variable i is 2, i want the loop to create 2 functions, the first function has to be executed when the button with the id btnEdit1 is being clicked, the second function needs to execute when a button with the id btnEdit2 is being clicked etc.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the HTML? You could use DOM relationship

Comment: You can create a function that receives the ID as argument. Then at that click handler, call the function with the j argument.

Comment: This code will create multiple functions. But since all of them use the same global `j` variable, all the functions will do the same thing. When the loop finishes `j == i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @HåkenLid

But does the code actually create the functions? When using the debugger and setting a breakpoint at the start of the loop it only iterates to the "    $('#btnEdit'+j).click(function() { " line, and then jumps back to the start.

Comment: You create the function as a single statement. The debugger treats it as one line. `$('#btnEdit'+j)` will be evaluated in the loop, but the function body will not be evaluated until you click a button. At that time `j` will be the same for every function.

Comment: Yes. That's what I would expect. But there might be some other bug. Your code in the question isn't really [mcve], so I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @HåkenLid

Just tried. Both buttons execute the function for the same user (User 2 in this case since the loop iterates twice). How would i fix this? As far as i understand i'm getting 2 functions that both start with the line $('#btnEdit2'), instead of $('#btnEdit1') and $('#btnEdit2')

Comment: Read the duplicate question. What you can do is to create a closure with a local variable instead of the global scope j.

Comment: @HåkenLid

I've read through it but didn't really get what it does. I tried one of the answers with "bind" but it didn't quite work. It still would only execute one function, as if there was only one button.

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. In this case, you can do it without closures as well, as suggested by the two answers. If you want to use `bind`, you have to make sure that the inner function takes the id value as an argument. `$('#btnEdit'+j).click((function(index){$("#prename"+index) [...] }).bind(null, j))`

Comment: @HåkenLid

I think i understand what i did wrong. Well, i'm using the solution Satpal provided, but thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple function I would recommend you to create single function.

Use custom `data-*` attribute to persist php variable `<?php echo $i; ?>` with edit `button` which can later be fetched using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

To attach event handler [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to target the elements and using [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) create a single method.

```
<input type="button" class="btnEdit" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="button<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Edit"></input>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnEdit', function(){
    var j = $(this).data('id');
    $("#prename"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#surname"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#function"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#prefix"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#phone_number"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#email"+j).removeAttr('disabled');
})
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand what this does. Could you go into more detail? If i use data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>", i won't all the input fields of the first user have data-id=1 ?

Comment: @zoefrankie, I am persisting the same php variable `<?php echo $i; ?>`with the `btnEdit` element using `data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>"`, which is fetched later and used to target the desired element

Comment: But i iterate through a php loop x amount of times to create the input fields. If i replace the id with data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>", won't all the fields of the first user have data-id=1? I'm confused since you removed the id=prename tag, but you're still trying to remove the attribute in js using the id. Isn't #prename+j undefined in this case?

Comment: @zoefrankiem, I removed `id="btnEdit<?php echo $i; ?>"`  with edit button as it was of no use. If you want you can keep it

Comment: My bad, i actually thought you were changing the input type text.

That being said i'm still not really sure what the code does.

What is this line for?

        var j = $(this).data('id');

And if you use the class to execute the function, won't the Button 2 execute the exact same function?

Comment: @zoefrankie,  Button 2 will execute the exact same function but with different `this` so `var j = $(this).data('id');` will be different thus it will target different element

Comment: I've tried and this works. After thinking about your code i also understand what it does. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you need this?

You can directly write with an `onClick` event in input as well with the parameter of your id (which means your `i` value) .

Please take this answer as a key idea

```
<input type="button" id="btnEdit<?php echo $i; ?>"
name="button<?php echo $i; ?>" onClick="btnEdit(?php echo $i; ?)" value="Edit"></input>

function btnEdit(id)
{
$("#prename"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#surname"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#function"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#prefix"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#phone_number"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#email"+id).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

**Note:** I  don't have experience in php . but this is common idea only